# Tips to make builds faster

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

Is there any way to make software builds / compilation faster ? We have a build tree c, c++ using makefile that takes close to 2Hrs for fresh builds. I came across few commercial solutions like ElectricAccelerator, Sparkbuild, are there any opensource equivalent ?

Comment: TWO HOURS!  Last time I saw build times like that was on overloaded VAXes.  Pesumably, this is a very large project.

What are you building it on?  Are all the files on network drives or copied to local?

Comment: @MartinJames I have seen 6 hours build time for some lisp, c, java project.

Comment: @Shiplu - I'm so sorry...  I would go insane.  If the build goes wrong after 5.9 hours, how do you stop yourself jumping off a high building?  What do you do to the developer who generated the unresolved external - is it very painful?

Comment: @Marin The build is done by hudson every 12 hours. If we something goes wrong SVN log finds the dev who to blame

Comment: Just curious, why are you opposed to a commercial solution?  Disclaimer: I'm the architect of ElectricAccelerator.

Comment: @EricMelski - hmmmm commercial solution needs $$$$$

Comment: @AUZKamath - [ElectricAccelerator Developer Edition](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator-dev.php) is currently free for one year, $120 / year thereafter.  So maybe you should say it needs $, rather than $$$$$. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to look at [distcc](http://www.distcc.org/), [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) and, of course, `-j` make option.

Answer (score 9):

A search on google might help in getting list of open source softwares.
W.r.t your code you can do the following to reduce build times:

- Use Forward declarations wherever possible.
- Use ***namespace declarations*** instead of ***namespace directive***.
- Make sure you do not have unnecessary includes.

Comment: What is *include declarations*?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Corrected the typo.Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In our company we had lots of product that has longer build time like 3-6 hours.

There are 2 techniques we used.

1. Use parallel build by `-j` option of `make`
2. **Mount RAM as a disk**. Then move all the files there and compile. But you need plenty of RAM for it. We used Amazons ec2 instances. It was quite expensive.

Comment: 'build time like 3-6 hours' - ouch!  I think I would find a new job.. :)

Comment: @MartinJames Dont worry, Hudson does it for me.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to simply run the build on faster hardware. I realize that this isn't *always* an option, but it's still something to consider.

As @Martin mentions, some specific sub-systems to upgrade include using as fast a disk as you can, like an SSD, adding more RAM, a faster CPU (and more cores, if your compiler can use them), and making sure the files being built are all local to the build machine (not on the network).

You should also give the build process as much of this resource pool as possible, so strip off all non-build-related processes and applications from the build machine. This will reduce any resource contention.

Comment: Yes - fast SSD arrays, loads of RAM, copy source to local folders for the build.

Comment: Exactly. Removing bottlenecks on the build machine are critical. Thanks for adding specific items to upgrade.

Comment: .. and surfing, bitTorrent and games run really fast as well, (in those short breaks between builds :)

Comment: I would say that bitTorrent and surfing speed depend _much_ more on the network speed, which the build _shouldn't_ depend on, so those won't see a boost, and most games depend much more on GPU performance, so you likely _won't_ see much of a speed boost for those, but yes, the OS will feel _much_ zippier.

Comment: OK, I admit it's difficult to justify to a technically knowledgeable manager that a build server really needs two high-end video cards and a 28" LED monitor :(

Comment: On the contrary...you have to have a large monitor to see the build status from across the room!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your configuration software, but we discovered a problem with clearcase.  Because of how it evaluates rules on a file by file basis, just opening a file can be a bottleneck.   Only even consider reading further if you are "stuck" with clearcase.

So, we discovered that by changing your include guards for header files, you can cut your build time to 1/30th the time (for us it did).

Basically, in your header files, you have an include guard at the top like :

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
your code
#endif
```

Then off somewhere else, you #include foo.h.   Right, well, we found that due to some horrible coupling of types files and such that some common headers got included hundreds of times for each .c file we compiled.   With the clearcase design flaw, that mean opening each of those files hundreds of times only to ignore the contents and close the file again.

So.. instead of just a #include for foo, use the guard to conditionally include foo.   Normally this is bad practice and a horrible maintenance nightmare (if someone starts changing the guards).

So.. in your .c file, you'd end up doing something like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef FOO_H
#include "foo.h"
#endif
#ifndef FOO_H
#include "foo.h"
#endif
... rest of your code implementation
```

Like I said... bad practice, but if you are using clearcase and its biting you with 3-4 build times (like we had)... may be worth considering (or just making a copy of your whole tree outside clearcase).   Or ditch clearcase.   Or do a better job with type inter-dependencies.

We were able to "fix" some of the most over-used includes and achieve pretty dramatic improvement in build times.

Answer (score 0):

Precompiled headers can, if employed correctly, drastically reduce build times.

Answer (score 0):

We use a combination of `distmake`, `ccache`, and a `makefile-generator` that creates a parallelizable makefile. `C/C++` builds can parallelize extremely well; often all `.o` files can be compiled in parallel.

`Distmake` is a distributed implementation of make, based on gnu make and released under GPL. I maintain it. It lets you parallelize across multiple hosts. This requires all the hosts have the same view of the filesystem, eg. NFS, so that the same command can run on any build host.

Turning off optimizations will tend to produce faster builds, if you have that option.

If you already use a parallel build architecture and it's still slow, you may just need to study it. Watch its progress with a stopwatch and see where it bottlenecks. Look for "long poles" that perhaps you didn't expect. Good luck.